# How to use the MediaWiki parser to get HTML from wikitext

Tags: php, parsing, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am trying to use Wikipedia's MediaWiki parser to parse Wikipedia mark up text to HTML.
I went through the manual here - https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser.php
However, since I am completely new to PHP, I am unable to write a test script,

Here is a sample input that I would want to parse and convert to HTML:

```
Shakespeare's sonnets
==Characters==
When analysed as characters, the subjects of the sonnets are usually referred
to as the Fair Youth, the Rival Poet, and the Dark Lady. The speaker expresses
admiration for the Fair Youth's beauty, and later has an affair with the Dark
Lady. It is not known whether the poems and their characters are fiction or
autobiographical; scholars who find the sonnets to be autobiographical, notably
[[A. L. Rowse]], have attempted to identify the characters with historical
individuals.
```

Comment: I used this project to parse
https://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/
This project gives me the HTML output, but retains hyperlinks and some tags that I wish to remove, So i would have to write a scrubber for it

But the documentation of mediawiki parser states that it defines functions to get what i need, so I wish to use it..Moreover its the official parser for Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to use PHP.  You can use Wikipedia's API (or the API on your own MediaWiki installation).  See [Parsing wikitext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal code for parsing wikitext (tested on MediaWiki 1.32):

```
$text = "Your [[wikitext]]";
$title = $skin->getTitle(); // Get the title object from somewhere or use $wgTitle
$parser = new Parser;
$parserOptions = new ParserOptions;
$parserOutput = $parser->parse( $text, $title, $parserOptions );
$html = $parserOutput->getText();
echo $html;
```

Bye!

Comment: I have been looking for code specific snippet to convert wikiText to html. All the answers I found use mediawiki API. Thanks for the snippet man. It works like charm. Peace

Comment: Hi @AzharSyed, I'm trying to convert wikitext to html. Could you please elaborate on where to run these commands provided by Sophivorus? I'm Windows 10, so I have not used this syntax before.

Comment: @LEAnhDung this is a php snippet.If you have mediawiki installed you can write a small extension and add this code there. To your extension you can send "wikitext" in request body and send  back the html to the client.

Comment: @AzharSyed Thank you so much for your hint. I will check it out. I'm having a problem of parsing (a simple) wikitext [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67365132/why-is-the-html-output-of-local-mediawiki-is-not-complete). I'm not sure if this is a common problem for MediaWiki on other machines. Could you please check if you also encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWPL http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/, it will work with a local copy of the wiki.
Load Dumps, Convert wie Datamaschine, import in DB, do what you want with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Link only answers are not best practice in SO, since answers become obsolete as link are removed/down or deleted.

Answer (score -1):

```
   //<myname></myname>    

    public static function onParserFirstCallInit( Parser $parser ){
        $parser->setHook('myname', 'MyClass::getOutputHtml');
    }
    public static function getOutputHtml(){
        $localParser = new Parser();
        $input = OtherClass::myOutput();
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $title = $context->getTitle();
        $parserOptions = new ParserOptions;
        $output = $localParser->parse($input, $title, $parserOptions);
        return $output->getText();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Roco, I'm trying to convert wikitext to html. Could you please elaborate on where to run these commands? I'm Windows 10, so I have not used this syntax before.