# Why is the html output of local MediaWiki is not complete?

Tags: mediawiki, parsoid

I'm using MediaWiki on my laptop Windows 10 to convert wikitext of entry `tease out`. The wikitext is

```
==English==

===Verb===
{{en-verb|*}}

# To [[unravel]]; {{lb|en|figuratively|by extension}} to [[determine]]; [[solve]].
#* '''2017,''' {{w|Jennifer S. Holland}}, ''For These Monkeys, It’s a Fight for Survival.'', National Geographic (March 2017)[http://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2017/03/macaques-monkeys-indonesia-endangered-pet-trade/]
#*: The researchers are '''teasing out''' fine details of the yaki’s private life.
#* {{quote-text|en|year=2017|author=Dr. Mike Roussell|title=Ask the Diet Doctor: Will CLA Help You Lose Weight?|passage=CLA is actually an umbrella term for several different types of trans fats similar in chemical structure. More research is necessary to '''tease out''' which type of CLA is actually the most beneficial (but more on that later).}}
# To separate as if by unraveling.
# To [[work out]], [[procure]], or [[extract]], usually by processes involving [[subterfuge]], [[diligence]], [[manipulation]], or [[coaxing]].
#* {{quote-text|en|year=2019|author=Andy Schneider|title=The Chicken Whisperer's Guide to Zero-Waste Chicken Keeping|passage=Well, early in the days of vitamin and mineral discovery, chickens were the research models for studies that eventually '''teased out''' information that we take for granted today.}}

[[Category:English phrasal verbs]]
[[Category:English phrasal verbs with particle (out)]]
```

The html from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tease_out is

[image]

The html from my local MediaWiki is

[image]

Could you please elaborate on why the wikitext is not parsed properly?

My MediaWiki version is `1.35.2-0`.

Comment: Please consult https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates, which I have included in my answer to your previous question. It should answer most of your template-related questions. 
Red links indicate that the linked pages are nonexistent. The pages won't display properly if you don't import the templates from Wiktionary.

Comment: Hi @user15517071, I have downloded the file `enwiktionary-20210420-templatelinks.sql` but don't know how to use it. Could you please elaborate or provide some reference on how to import the templates?